# The suspension of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^3 \vee S^5$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, projective-space

I am looking for a relatively simple way to see that $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^3 \vee S^5$.

Both the Euler characteristic of a space and its homology groups are invariant under homotopy equivalence, so I tried to consider these concepts. However, the Euler characteristic of both spaces is equal to $-1$, and the homology groups of both spaces are also isomorphic.

In the answer posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433511/order-of-the-suspension-of-the-hopf-map/4433633#4433633), the author considers Steenrod squares to show that the homotopy equivalence can't exist, but this is a topic that I'm not quite familiar with.

Should I try to use the Freudenthal suspension theorem or something related to homotopy groups? Or, perhaps, cohomology rings and the cup product? I do know that the cup product of $H^{\ast}(\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2)$ is trivial (see the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298938/cup-product-in-cohomology-ring-of-a-suspension)); can I show that the cup product in $H^{\ast}(S^3 \vee S^5)$ is nontrivial?

Edit: As commented below, the cup product in $H^{\ast}(S^3 \vee S^5)$ is also trivial, so this won't help here, either.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you should be able to see that cup products in $H^*(S^3\vee S^5)$ are trivial. The square of any element in $H^3$ (resp. $H^5$) is trivial because they live in $H^6$ (resp. $H^{10}$), and if you take the cup product of the generator of these two groups, then the result lives in $H^8$ which is also trivial. Therefore, the cohomology ring structure is not enough.

Comment: If you really don't want to use Steenrod squares, you should compute $\pi_4$ of both complexes.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Actually, this question came out of wanting to show that $\pi_4(S^3)$ is nontrivial, since the calculation that $\pi_4(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ also uses some  advanced topics (such as the Serre spectral sequence) that I'm also not quite familiar with.

Comment: @michiganbiker898 $\pi_4(S^3)$ can be calculated from Freudenthal suspension theorem. But really I think you have some things backwards; things like the Serre spectral sequence and Steenrod square are "easy" in comparison to calculating without them.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yeah, upon further inspection, you're right. Actually, I found a bachelor's thesis that does a great job explaining what I'm after using Steenrod operations. It is Example 2.1.1 here: http://web.math.ku.dk/~jg/students/guldberg.bs.2009.pdf

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks for the help!